# ADO Recordset Returns Old (Stale) Data

Tags: vba, excel, recordset

I have written VBA code that uses ADODB recordset to retrieve data from an Excel worksheet in order to populate a user form. The worksheet is replaced with new data each time the code is run.

As of a few weeks ago, I started having an issue where the recordset object will not return the correct data, but instead, returns the data that was used in a previous session. This happens even after closing the Excel file and re-opening it.

For example, I will run the code with dataset A, then close the Excel file. I re-open the Excel file, replace the worksheet with dataset B, and run the code. Instead of returning dataset B, it will return dataset A. When this happens, I have confirmed that the worksheet in fact contains dataset B, and not A.
To provide some more background information, I believe this started happening when I switched from using the ACE connection string instead of JET. I was forced to make this transition because I started getting errors with the JET connection string. The connection string I used can be found below.

I would appreciate any kind of feedback related to this issue. If more information is needed, please let me know.

```
strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & mstrFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"""
```

Comment: A couple of questions. Firstly where does this VBA code reside? I'm assuming that it's not in the same Excel file that contains the data, in which case it doesn't really matter. If the VBA code _is_ in a different file/application, then the Excel with your data in it doesn't actually need to be open for the code to work. Secondly, you say you re-open the Excel, change the data and then run the code again - before you re-run the code, do you save the changed Excel?

Comment: The VBA code resides in the macro-enabled Excel file, and so does the data (in a worksheet). The Excel file is not saved before re-running the code.

Comment: VBA code and data both in the *same* Excel file? So why do you need a connection string at all? But if you _are_ using a connection string, then not saving the file might account for your problem. While you are editing the file, your connection string will be pointing to the original unsaved copy of the file. Save the file before running the code and see if this works.

Comment: Eliminate the possibility that `mstrFile` points to the wrong place by replacing it with `ThisWorkbook.FullName` Also, there should be a semi-colon at the end of the connection string: `IMEX=1"";"`

Comment: Skippy - Saving the file after importing the data did it. It makes sense. As far as connection strings go, it was my understanding that you still have to use a connection string, even if it's pointing to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved (thanks to Skippy). Saving the file after importing the new data into the worksheet solved the issue. Without saving the file, the connection was pointing to a version of the file that contained stale data.